# Nagios check a number inside an API response

Tags: http, nagios

Ok so I want to use Nagios to check a 3rd party service I am subscribed to. They have an API that displays how much credit I have left. I originally bought 5000 credit and I need to have a warning when it reaches 500 and a critical when less than 200 credits left.

The API response looks like this (not JSON not XML!):

`0<BR>credit=3438`

Which plugin can I use to achieve this check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably have to write your own.

https://nagios-plugins.org/doc/guidelines.html